# Is there a way to rename my migration file without causing problems?

Tags: php, laravel-5, database-migration

I named one of my migration files add_slug_to_users where I meant to name it add_slug_to_posts. Not a big deal but it is misleading for someone else who is looking at my code.

I tried to rename it but the next time I ran php artisan migrate I got an error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] Class 'AddSlugToPosts' not found
```

Is there a way to rename this file or am I stuck? I am using Laravel version 5.2.45.

Comment: Go into the DB and manually edit the Migration name

Comment: This would be an issue on any environment that migration has already been run. If this migration has already gone into staging or production I would not touch it.